# How to calculate a field based on retrieved fields and incorporate into JSON in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a controller method which retrieves all the data from one table based on a userID. I want to do a simple addition of two of the integer fields in that table for that user and have that as part of the returned JSON. This is what I have so far:

```
def show
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      # Here we need to remove the layout because the request
      # is done via ajax and the layout is already loaded.

      format.json {  render json: @user.to_json } 
    end
```

The fields I want to add together to make this new field are 'Score1' and 'Score2'. I assume I have to do something like @user.OverallScore = @user.Score1 + @user.Score2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define an instance method `score_sum` in the `User` model

```
def score_sum
  self.Score1 + self.Score2
end
```

and  use `@user.to_json(:methods => [:score_sum])` in your controller.

Answer (score 2):

The shortest way to handle this is probably something like this:

In your `User` model, add a method:

```
class User
  def overall_score
    score1 + score2
  end
end
```

Then in your controller, you keep what you have and change the last line into:

```
format.json {  render json: @user.as_json(methods: [:overall_score]) }
```

Also I suggest to use `as_json` and leave the hash-to-json conversion to the render method itself, unless you need to manipulate the converted string itself

Comment: @Зелёный I'm ok with your edit, only if you change the question too. Even if the style was wrong, I was using the same style Sebastian was using

Comment: then this `Score1 + Score2` should be `self.Score1 + self.Score2`

Comment: Mh? No absolutely, you **need** `self` during assignment, otherwise, you can use the fields without `self` as long as there isn't a local variable previously assigned with the same name. It's also a good convention to use `self` only during assignments

Comment: i do not want hollywar, and know all what you say, using name-convention in some language make the code readable. I am not sure but if some column have camel case name `Score1` it should raise errors about `uninitialized constant`, so i put `self.` to avoid it. IMO

Comment: Sorry you are definitely write, I thought you were referring to use self on `self.score1` etc, not on `self.Score1`

Comment: Thanks! I used Adam's answer with self assignments as well. I guess wither would have been fine though. Thanks again